# .Net MVC 3 & Entity framework 4.1 timeout expired of executing the database command (stored procedure)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Is there any way to increase the timeout limit of the database command (stored procedure)? I tried to add this in the connection string in web.config, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=300
```

I am currently use EF 4.1 for some stored procedure calls and I am also use the ado.net to call some stored procedures having table-valued parameters as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it the connection you're timing out on or the execution of the command?  It might be the command timing out, which I believe are two different things entirely.

I'm a novice at this but it's my understanding that there's a difference between the connection timeout (how long to wait for a connection to the database - which is likely timing out if there's a problem connecting in general) and a command timeout (how long to wait when executing command).  I had some issues on a project executing long-running commands.  I think the default was 30 seconds thought it may differ by DB.  In that situation, I could set it to a value of 0 and it wouldn't time out.  Wondering if this is really the command timeout that you want to increase instead.

I believe you have to set the command timeout on a per-command basis as part of the command.
[Here's a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429594/command-timeout-with-entity-framework-4-1-code-first) about that.

Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, I think in my case it should be the command timeout. Since the stored procedure takes a very long time to run.